# wordpress background image not showing after logout

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello i have made a child theme and on the main page there's big image.While i'm logged in, wordpress shows the image i want to be displayed 
[image]

but when i log out there's no image.
[image]
 I've been searching for css rule to find background-image property but i didn't find it. What's the problem ? Thanks in advance 
The parent theme is belize

Comment: Can you please send me your website link?

Comment: www.chatabaryla.pl

Comment: As i can see that i have opened this URL and i am able to see the background image without login. Try with after clear cache

Comment: im getting a fatal error on your child theme header, delete it and build it again. then Ravi is correct - clear your cache.

Comment: I fixed header error but now i get error in line `$this->theme_name = $theme->parent()->get( 'Name' );`